# Axios get request hangs, no error, catch not fired

Tags: node.js, express, axios, spotify

When I make a GET request with axios on node it just hangs, the catch is not thrown and error caught.

Am not sure how to debug this, no error is thrown. I am firing the spotify API, but surely if there was an issue on there side, I would get some response?

For a while I was getting a ECONNRESET error, my internet is not too stable. But this error stopped being throw.

I have tried using fetch, same issue. I have gone back to classic promise syntax. It has been working fine since now.

This method is called and logged.

```
"node": "10.0.0",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
```

```
    function tryFetchForPlaylists(usersCred) {
        console.log('req method called ', usersCred)
        let playlistData;

        try {
            playlistData = axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + usersCred.userId + '/playlists',
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + usersCred.accessToken,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                });

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            if (err.response.status === 401) {
                console.error(err);
                return {statusCode: 401};
            }
        }

        playlistData.then((res) => {
            console.info('response status',res.status)
            if(res.status === 200) {
                return res;
            }
        });
    }
```

'req method called 'is logged and the creds are there, nothing else, just hangs.

Comment: `axios.get()` returns a promise, not a finished value.  You need to either use `await` or `.then()` on that promise to get the value.  And, `try/catch` will only get errors if you're using `await`.  Otherwise, you should use `.catch()` to see errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 It seems to be work if I use `.then()` and `.catch()` - i get the JSON in a 200 which is all good. But returning it to to a function that uses `await` does not work. ` let status = await tryFetchForPlaylists(userCreds);
    console.log('waiting for status ', status)` status is `undefined`

Comment: Well `tryFetchForPlaylists()` is just implemented wrong so you can't `await` it.  You have to fix it's implementation.  It seems like you need to do some reading about how you get errors from a promise.  `try/catch` ONLY works for that inside an async function and with promises you are using `await` on.  If you aren't doing `await fetch()`, then you have to use `fetch().then().catch()` to catch the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to store the call inside a function. Just use the call as a promise.

```
 function tryFetchForPlaylists(usersCred) {
        console.log('req method called ', usersCred)
        let playlistData;

        return axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + usersCred.userId + '/playlists',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + usersCred.accessToken,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then((data) => {
             // return your data here...
            })
            .catch((err) => {})


    }
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I had been using `async` and `await` in the `try` `catch` block before. Now seems to work with your configuration. I do get the JSON, but can't return to the caller function for some reason. I am using `await` in the caller function, but it is still undefined.

Comment: @godhar  I made some edits that should allow you to return the data to the caller.  Make sure to return the `axios` promise then return the data as well.  If this helps you solve your problem, would you mind marking it as the solution?  Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to `return` that axios function - damn! I will upvote you @caden311